# Docker Compose Wordpress Persistant Plugin Install

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

How do I make it such that I can upload plugins and have them persist on docker compose setup? I'm working with wordpress 4. My docker compose is for a plugin I'm developing, and I would like to have it automatically install my plugins. Right now I'm trying to use volumes to fudge it, and persist them, but the directory is not writable.

Or is there a way to say add these plugins on setup with the default wordpress image?

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:4.9-php7.2-apache
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes:
         - ".:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/xxx:ro"
         - plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/:Z
volumes:
    db_data:
    plugins:
```